# How to use Spring Security for x.509 SSL authentication in SOAP services?

Tags: spring, ssl, soap, spring-security, x509

I would like to secure a SOAP web service at two levels: first, requests themselves have to be signed and encrypted with WSS4J, second, the whole communication should take place over SSL with client certificate authentication.

My problem is that Spring Security does not recognize the certificate.

The client does this:

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance( "SSLv3" );

  KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() );

  KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance( KeyStore.getDefaultType() );
  ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource( "ClientKeyStore.jks" );
  is = res.getInputStream();
  String password = getPasswordFromCallback();
  ks.load( is, password.toCharArray() );
  kmf.init( ks, password.toCharArray() );

  sc.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null );

  BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) service;

  bp.getRequestContext().put( "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", sc.getSocketFactory() );


  service.[method execution here]();
```

The x509 filter is configured on the server, so indeed when the client connects, X509AuthenticationFilter.extractClientCertificate gets executed. Here is this method:

```
private X509Certificate extractClientCertificate(HttpServletRequest request) {
    X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

    if (certs != null && certs.length > 0) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("X.509 client authentication certificate:" + certs[0]);
        }

        return certs[0];
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("No client certificate found in request.");
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, "certs" is always null here. Why?

By the way, the Tomcat connector is configured so:

```
<Connector
       protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" keyPass="changeit"
       clientAuth="optional" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

(I wouldn't like to enforce client authentication, as it is not required in applications).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If you already have a certificate keystore hooked up in Wssj for encryption, why not use Wssj also for authentication?
In case you use spring ws you can find some info here http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/security.html

Comment: Hi! Actually the project specification expects authentication to take place at the SSL level but I have finally solved it with WSSJ. I suppose the problem might have been a certificate chain issue (I have experienced the same thing with WSSJ too): that a certificate doesn't get sent to the server if it does not have a trusted signer which is in the server's keystore. However I assumed that if I import the client certificate itself to the server keystore then it becomes trusted automatically, but seemingly this is not how it works...

Comment: Yes, I realized that and changed clientAuth to optional, but it unfortunately did not solve my original problem. When I turned on Java SSL debugging, it showed "null certificate chain" on the server side.